# How to fit large width Table data into double column format?

Tags: tables, double-sided

I am using the [Conferance Latex Format](https://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2021/submission.html), you may see the detail formating code on this given link.
I want to insert a table in the double-column format. Here is the content I want to format in the latex
[image]

I made some basic code for it but the output visualization is quite small. Here is the output of Latex code
[image]

Please see Table1.

This is the code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{c*{6}{>{$}c<{$}}}
\hline
    \text{Name}        & \text{Reference}       & \text{S/A}       & \text{Advantages}  & \text{Disadvantages}   & API  \\
    \hline
 Abcde (abcc) & 43,50 & S & There is value in the demanding of high data & It do not thing any thing you can make better & Abbccc & Python, C++ \\
 69.8\pm 9.5 & 93.6\pm 3.6 & 86.9\pm 8.4 & 91.5\pm 4.5 & 94.9\pm 5.4 \\
97.0\pm 2.9 & 99.2\pm 1.8 & 99.6\pm 1.4 & 98.3\pm 2.9 & 99.6\pm 1.4 \\
97.8\pm 3.1 & 95.3\pm 3.1 & 96.2\pm 2.5 & 92.4\pm 3.3 & 97.5\pm 3.0 \\
77.5\pm 7.2 & 90.2\pm 4.1 & 90.2\pm 5.7 & 88.1\pm 4.8 & 91.6\pm 4.9 \\
 88.0      & 95.1      & 94.1      & 93.5      & 96.5 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I believe you know the drill: Don't just post an image; please do also show the code that gives rise to the issue you wish to fix. In particular, it's absolutely essential that you inform us about the document class you employ and about the code that generates the tables. *Why* is it essential? Because, sadly, nobody who frequents this site seems to have reliable psychic divination powers. Thus, unless you tell us exactly what it is you've done so far, the chances that anyone will be able to guess it correctly for you are vanishingly small.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I edited my post with the code and conference formating link. Now you can check. If you need anything else please feel free to ask

Comment: You can nest your table in a `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle), to temporarily leave the two-column mode.

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables (your image shows why!) put your long headings in a parbox or nested tabular so they are not on one line, and if necessary use `table*` so it spans over both columns,

Comment: your example is still incomplete you are requiring that people guess a preamble to make it work, examples are always best if they start `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` (you can use `article` class for the example even if using a specific class in the real document

Comment: We are not allowed to overlap the second column

Comment: @DavidCarlisle everything is given in the conference web link, you may see it.

Comment: No it should be a self contained small example in the question.

Comment: But this is essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/1090

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic:

You need to be aware that the members of this site are volunteers. They answer on questions in their spare time. In order to be able to answer as many questions as possible, it is normal that that they expect that the questions are clear and comprehensible, that they do not need to search the web for data known to asker etc., that the questions contain MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but a complete compilable document) that reproduces the problem of interest.

So be so kind, and provide in your question all what you asked in comment. If you not do so, we can only guess about some information, which are essential ion preparation of answer.- For example, the following example, is based in guessing:

On-topic:

IN MWE below is assumed, that your document has two columns.

- In such document for table, which span both columns you should use `table*` environment.
- Some table cells has very long text. For it is sensible to use column type which breaks text into multiple lines. Example of such column tapes are `p{<column width>}`, or `X` and its derivatives from `tabularx` table environment (as is selected in MWE below).
- Numbers in tale can be simply and concise to write by employing `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcC{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{C}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcL{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{L}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of figure* on the same page

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}[b]
\caption{hello2 testing}
\label{1234}
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l *{5}{S[table-format=2.1(2),
                                        separate-uncertainty]}
                             }
    \toprule
Name   
    &   \mcC{Reference}  
                &   \mcC{S/A}    
                        &   \mcC{Advantages}
                                    &   \mcC{Disadvantages}
                                                &   \mcC{API}               \\
    \midrule
Abcde (abcc) 
    &   43,50   &   \mcL{There is value in the demanding of high data}
                            &   \mcL{It do not thing any thing you can make better}
                                        &   \mcC{Abbccc}
                                                    &   \mcC{Python, C++}   \\
    \addlinespace
B   & 69.8(95)  & 93.6(36)  & 86.9(84)  & 91.5(45)   & 94.9(54)  \\
C   & 97.0(29)  & 99.2(18)  & 99.6(14)  & 98.3(29)  & 99.6(14)  \\
D   & 97.8(31)  & 95.3(31)  & 96.2(25)  & 92.4(33)  & 97.5(30)  \\
E   & 77.5(72)  & 90.2(41)  & 90.2(57)  & 88.1(48)  & 91.6(49)  \\
F   & {88.0}    & {95.1}    & {94.1}    & {93.5}    & {96.5}    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]